# In Extjs Difference b/w Ext.ajax.request and Ext.data.Connection

Tags: java, extjs

i have small doubt in EXTJS, (i.e)can explain what is main difference between Ext.data.Connection and  Ext.Ajax.request

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing from the version 4.2.1 documentation:

> Ext.Ajax.request is a singleton instance of Ext.data.Connection. This class is used to communicate with your server side code. In general, this class will be used for all Ajax requests in your application. The main reason for creating a separate Ext.data.Connection is for a series of requests that share common settings that are different to all other requests in the application.

If you want more information then you should probably consult the documentation:

[Ext.data.Connection](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection)

[Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)